# Xcode 4.2 "cell reuse indentifier in nib (Cell) does not match the identifier used to register the nib (ThisCell)"

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, xcode4.2

I'm trying to use the new StoryBoard feature of Xcode 4.2 and keep getting this error when using a Table View with a custom cell.

`cell reuse indentifier in nib (Cell) does not match the identifier used to register the nib (ThisCell)`

I've set the class of my custom cell to my custom UITableViewCell class and set the Identifier to "ThisCell" in IB.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {     
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ThisCell";
//TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ThisCell"];
TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
return cell;
```

I have no idea where "Cell" is coming from.  Any ideas?  I tried loading a custom cell in another project, and it seems to work fine, I just can't find any documentation on this error to find out what I messed up in the current project.

Thanks

Answer (score 16):

The error message states that in your nib the cell is identified as "Cell"—you need to look in the xib file that defines your custom cells for configuration of the Cell Reuse Identifier, and set that to ThisCell... Or just change ThisCell to Cell in this code.

Comment: That's what I thought, so I double checked the Identifier in XCode and found it to be "ThisCell".  Also, I found if I have mismatched identifiers from the code and nib iOS doesn't error out, it just doesn't load that cell from the nib (and instead loads up an empty cell)

Comment: So what happens if you just change "ThisCell" to "Cell" in your code above?

Comment: If I change both identifiers to "Cell" I don't get an error, cut `cell` is null after the expression.  I'm guessing I have some weird typo somewhere or maybe a funky import (I copied these files from another project, so maybe I grabbed a funky version) because in all my other projects this works fine.  Thanks for the ideas though! I'll let you know if I find something that I'm doing wrong

Comment: You probably have the ReuseIdentifier in you nib said to something else. Check your nib, if you set the ReuseIdentifier trough code you can leave it empty there

Comment: Hey Tyler, what was ultimately your solution? I'm having the exact same problem. I switched the identifier and it worked but then it loaded an empty cell as well.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at following 2 places in your project. And make sure they both string identifiers are same.

[image: Check in Storyboard/Xib here]
[image: In code check this line in cellforRowAtIndexPath method]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is as @Duncan Babbage described. It happens when there is some type of conflicts in the reuse identifier for the same instance. (In my case, I defined two different reuse identifiers in both Storyboard and code and they were conflicting each other )

- you can also look for "Cell" outside the .xib file, specifically in all project files.

[image]